# Writing a lab manual, need to know how to make the DC voltage symbol from a multimeter

Tags: symbols, circuits, physics

I am working on a lab manual  for my school and I am getting to the circuits labs. I want to tell the students what symbol on the multimeter to use, it is a V with two lines over it, top line is regular, and the bottom line is dashed. I've included a picture. [image: The symbol I want to type]. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with that link and using the accents package to have it above the V like I wanted

Answer (score 0):

This got me exactly what I wanted

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mathdirectcurrent}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\mathdirectcurrentinner\relax}}
\newcommand{\mathdirectcurrentinner}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$#1=$}%
  \vbox to 1.15ex {\offinterlineskip
    \hbox to \dimen0{\hss\leaders\hrule\hskip1.0\dimen0\hss}
    \vskip.35ex
    \hbox to \dimen0{\hss
      \leaders\hrule\hskip.25\dimen0
      \hskip.2\dimen0
      \leaders\hrule\hskip.25\dimen0
      \hskip.2\dimen0
      \leaders\hrule\hskip.25\dimen0
    \hss}
\vfill
}%
}
\newcommand{\textdirectcurrent}{\mathdirectcurrentinner{\textstyle}{}}
\newcommand{\dcc}[1]{\accentset{\mathdirectcurrent}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\dcc{\text{V}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile in its current form: per the manual, you must load `accents` _after_ `amsmath`.